# How to access outer innerHTML of some nested div in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, click, getelementbyid

To keep it simple, I have below html code:

```
<div class = "customers" data-popover="true" data-html=true
 data-content="
  <table>
      <c:forEach items="${element.first}" var="btnVal" varStatus="loop"> 
        <c:if test="${not loop.first}">
        <tr> <button onclick='setTestname(innerHTML)' class='btn btn-primary'> ${btnVal}</button> </tr>
        <tr>&nbsp</tr>
        </c:if>
      </c:forEach>  
   </table>
  ">
 <br>${element.first.get(0)}
</div>
```

Here I am trying to use the value of the clicked button using below javascript function:

```
function setTestname(test){
  test = test.toString().trim();

  document.getElementById('hiddenCostomer').value=test;                     
  setLogfilename(test);
  document.getElementById('form1').submit();
}
```

Above code works fine, but I am not sure abt how to access value of `div` as well. I want to pass two values to `setTestname`

1. `${btnVal}`
2. `${element.first.get(0)}`

How to get value of `${element.first.get(0)}`

EDIT : I want the exact value of `div` on which the button is clicked , not the entire DOM.

Comment: Customer is spelt with a **u**, not like costumes, check your other code uses consistent spelling if using the code from Gor181
`hiddenCostomer` vs `hiddenCustomer`

Comment: @Mousey:  That's not a prob. My code is working. I need to select the `div` whose btn has been clicked. Plz help

Answer (score 0):

You should add the value to a data attribute and then get it, something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="myid" data-mydata="${element.first.get(0)}"></div>
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById("myid").getAttribute("data-mydata");
```

Comment: I have class, I think what you are suggesting is for ID

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the class name of the div you want to fetch contents of.

```
setTestName(innerHTML, 'customers')
```

Then use customers as:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('customers')
```

which will return the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

`<c:set var="BtnIndex" value="${0}"/>`

then I set

`<tr> <button onclick='setTestname(innerHTML,${BtnIndex + 0})' class='btn btn-primary' > ${btnVal} ${BtnIndex + 0}</button> </tr>`

I set one counter and assigned each div a unique number. Later , i fetched the value from array of class `customers` from that unique counter as index

```
function setTestname(test,btnIndex){
    test = test.toString().trim();
    btnIndex = btnIndex.toString();

    var elemArray = document.getElementsByClassName('customers');
    for(var i = 0; i < elemArray.length; i++){
        elemArray[i].id = i;
    }

    var elem = document.getElementById(elemArray[btnIndex].id);
    var mainDir = elem.innerHTML;
}
```

It worked !!! Bingo